# Memory management with ARC - performance issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have some general beginner questions regarding memory management with ARC. I'm experiencing some performance issues in my app - both on my device and on the simulator. The performance issue only appears when I run the simulator in "retina" mode, therefore I think that I must have a "memory" issue. I have also seen "received memory warning" in my log when I tested the app on my device.

First, when I creates UIImages to be used in a subview, should I set that image to nil after I have assigned it to the subview? Example:

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
// Should I set image && imageView to nil here?
```

Does this also apply to other local variables and or instance variables?

Second, what is the correct ARC way to create instance variables, I currently use,

```
UiView  * view;

// And implement it in @implementation
view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Any guidance and tips would be appreciated. Links to good ARC resources would also be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is ok. There is no problem with memory management there. Only thing that can cause problems is `[UIImage imageNamed:]` because it cashes loaded images. Try to use `[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:]` instead.

You can find good article about ARC [here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20LearnMasterCocos2dForIphoneGameDevelopment%20%28Learn%20&%20Master%20cocos2d%20for%20iPhone%20Game%20Development%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I have located the performance issue to the way I handle rotations. My current rotation code looks like thins: `self.pageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * (-90) / 180.0);
        self.pageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.pageView.transform,0.8375,0.8375);
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(-75.7, 73.7, 480.0f, 268.0f);` When i comment these lines out, the performance is OK. Think I'm going to create two separate views for landscape and portrait and see if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the ARC related questions that you have are fine. You do not manually need to set any variables to nil; they will automatically be set to nil when they go out of scope. ARC figures out how to retain/release instance variables, so no need to do anything special there either.

As you mentioned, the problem occurs when you run your application on a retina display. Considering that your code in question is closely related to images, it is my suspicion that the problem is image related. It may be that `Image.png` is high resolution, and on a retina device is allocated in a way that uses a lot of memory.

I suggest that you try:

- **a)** calling `initWithFrame:` on the image view and later calling `setImage:`, this way the image view will not be resized or handled strangely because of weird `UIImage` retina behavior.
- **b)** manually resize your resource, `Image.png`, to be smaller. This can be done through any basic image editor, such as Preview.